# pass parameter from CreateView to template (Django)

Tags: python, django

I've seen a similar question, alas it has not been answered.
I have an app that features Entries (like blog entries) which include a part called SubEntry. I want the users to be able to report SubEntries (i.e. press the button 'report', fill some fields and the application sends an email to admins, saving the report in db is nice to have):

The flow should be like that: at the view EntryDetails (url: /entry/entry-title/) the user may click on the SubEntry part. The modal opens and the subentry is visualized in the modal as enlarged, with a button/link underneath 'Report the SubEntry'. Then it's possible to click on the 'Report the SubEntry' button and two fields appear - reason of reporting and contact detail of the reporter (here I am just toggling the visibility of the fields). I manage to display the form (with get overriden - overriding get_form_kwargs causes the error No Entry with that title) but either the Entry or its attributes are not displayed...

My questions are:
1) is creating a model for Reporting (ReportSubEntry) a decent approach?
2) I can't seem to pass the needed variable (an Entry object that is to be a ForeignKey for a SubEntry object that is being created) from CreateReport view to the report_subentry.html.

any thoughts, advice? Python 3.5, Django 1.10

models.py:

```
class ReportSubentry(models.Model):
    Entry = models.ForeignKey('Entry')
    details = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact = models.EmailField()
```

forms.py:

```
class ReportEntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ReportSubEntry
        fields = ['details', 'contact', 'project']
```

views.py:

```
class CreateReport(CreateView):
    model = ReportSubEntry
    form_class = ReportSubEntryForm
    template_name = 'understand/report_subentry.html'

# tried two methods to pass the variables:
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = None
    title = kwargs.get('title')
    kwargs['entry'] = get_object_or_404(Entry, title=title)
    return super(CreateReport, self).get(request, **kwargs)

def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
    title = kwargs.get('title')
    kwargs['entry'] = get_object_or_404(Entry, title=title)
    return kwargs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've solved this issue.
The only solution that worked for me was overriding the get method of the ReportSubentry without calling the get method of the superclass:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = None
    title = kwargs.get('title')
    entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, title=title)
    context_data = self.get_context_data()
    context_data.update(entry=entry)
    return self.render_to_response(context_data)
```

Please feel free to discuss it.

Answer (score 0):

The current model that you are using `ReportSubEntry` is perfect and there is no need to change it.

In your forms.py `ReportEntryForm` you have to use `relatedfields` to be able to correctly serialize the data. There is no need to override anything. When user clicks on report the sub entry you have to pass the pk of Entry model as it is required to know which entry is reported. I am assuming that since you are successfully displaying the entries pk of those are present. When you receive the pk with other two fields you get the corresponding entry for pk and then pass the object to `ReportSubentry.objects.create` method.

The reportentry form should not contain foreign key. You have two choices for that. First is remove that field and pass the pk of entry from frontend using ajax calls or use javascript to add a disabled input field which contains pk of entry when user clicks on report subentry.

Comment: Thank you, Arpit, for a prompt answer but alas I seem not to get it right... I haven't found a relatedfields attributes documentation, so I just added relatedfields attribute to ReportPictureForm's Meta:  relatedfields = ['details', 'contact']. And nothing has changed. I've tried related_fields, put it outside Meta - nothing worked, though

Comment: related fields are for serializer its not applicable to your case

Comment: Aha, one more thing - SubEntry is just a picture, I can get to its url only by Entry (SubEntry's url is a field of an Entry). I need it when the form template is rendered (after get) And it is the only thing I am missing at the moment - the picture (it's url). So your suggestion would be to use the javascript?

Comment: yeah you have to use js. Actually js will handle it better

Comment: ok, so I should get the Entry pk from the url, because I'm not able to pass it via the view methods.

Comment: yep correct. if you have more doubts then move this discussion to chats